# x86 Assembly Fixed-Point Division

Tags: assembly, x86, division, fixed-point

I had a problem with my homework. I was supposed to divide an 8.8 fixed point number that was stored in `AX` by Pi (3.141592) and store the result back in `AX`.

I wrote:

```
mov dl, ah
mov ah, al
mov bx, 804
div bx
```

The program is called automatically and given a value in `AX` in order to test it. However, I did not manage to pass all tests. Anyone have any idea how I can make it more precise?

Comment: How is this supposed to work?  Is DH already zero, and you're left-shifting AX into DX:AX?  But you're leaving the low byte of AX unmodified, so it's like `DX:AX = (AX << 8) | (AX & 0xFF)`  IDK if that makes any sense.  And why `804` (0x324) as a divisor?

Answer (score 2):

Just because the original value was in 8.8 fixed point format, doesn't mean that your divisor has to be in 8.8 fixed point format.

To achieve the maximum precision; double the magnitude of both the numerator and divisor at the same time, until doing so would cause an overflow. For example:

```
(value << 8) / (PI << 8) = (value << 8) / 804
(value << 9) / (PI << 9) = (value << 9) / 1608
(value << 10) / (PI << 10) = (value << 9) / 4216
...
(value << 13) / (PI << 13) = (value << 13) / 25736
(value << 14) / (PI << 14) = (value << 14) / 51472 = BEST
(value << 15) / (PI << 15) = (value << 15) / 102944 = DIVISOR OVERFLOWS
```

This gives code like:

```
    xor dx,dx           ;dx:ax = ax = value << 8

    shld dx,ax,6
    shl ax,6            ;dx:ax = value << 14

    mov bx,51472        ;bx = PI << 14

    div bx              ;ax = value << 14 / PI << 14 = value / PI
```

Note that this will give you an integer result (and not a factional or fixed point result). If you need an 8.8 fixed point result, then you need to shift the numerator an extra 8, like:

```
    xor dx,dx           ;dx:ax = ax = value << 8

    shld dx,ax,14
    shl ax,14           ;dx:ax = value << 22

    mov bx,51472        ;bx = PI << 14

    div bx              ;ax = value << 22 / PI << 14 = value / PI << 8
```

Both of these can be improved a tiny little bit more by rounding the result up if the remainder is not less than half of the divisor. In other words:

```
    cmp dx,51472/2      ;Should result be rounded up?
    jb .done            ; no, remainder is too small
    inc ax              ; yes, round the result up
.done:
```

WARNING: I'm not sure which CPU/s you're intending to support. If I remember correctly, the `SHLD` instruction wasn't supported on the original 8086 and may need to be replaced with an alternative (`mov dx,ax` then shift it right). For modern 80x86 CPUs (since 80386) you can improve precision more by doing a 32-bit division, but it's not really going to matter much due to the low precision of the original "8.8 fixed point" value.

Comment: Yes, shld was new in 386, but is easy to do without for this because you're just shifting into a zeroed register.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I will definitely try it